# Some CSS attributes not working well in JavaFX 2.1

Tags: css, javafx-2

I was not sure if it was me, that was not using the right attributes to style controls via CSS.  But today I tested one example from the Ensemble application and noticed it was not working there either.

The one I find most difficult to set right is:  **-fx-text-fill**
To change the text color of a label for example:

```
#pill-left:selected .label {
 /* -fx-text-fill: black; */
 -fx-text-fill:red;
 -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , white , 0, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
}
```

No matter what I put there, the text always uses the default value color.

I'm using JavaFx 2.1.   Maybe this is already fixed in 2.2, but I figure I should point that out, as it is something very basic.

Comment: Have you tried `#pill-left .label{}` only. Cause I don't think there is a ":selected" pseudo-class of the Label or Node.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, and many other things without success

Comment: Just curious how are you using the "pill-left" in your code?

Comment: just use `.text` instead of `.label`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some extensive testing,  I managed to make it work using StyleSheets.

The key is to remove the **.label** attribute and use just the control's ID, appending the states (*:hover*, *:selected*, etc) as needed.

```
    #pill-left {
    -fx-padding: 5;
    -fx-text-fill:red;
    -fx-border-image-source: url("left-btn.png");
    -fx-border-image-slice: 4 4 4 4 fill;
    -fx-border-image-width: 4 4 4 4;
    -fx-border-image-insets: 0;
    -fx-border-image-repeat: stretch;
    -fx-background-color: null !important; 
}

#pill-left:hover, #pill-left:hover:selected { -fx-text-fill:blue; }
#pill-left:selected { 
    -fx-text-fill:green;
    -fx-border-image-source: url("left-btn-selected.png"); }
```

As this is all based on code examples taken directly from the ensemble project, that we assume is correct.  Many programmers are going to find themselves pulling their hair like I did over this issue.

Anyhow, this is an important lesson learnt on how to use styleSheets with Javafx, avoiding when possible to use anything else than the ID to specify some attributes like the text color.

Answer (score 5):

95% sure this is a bug.

The workarround you need to use `-fx-fill: red;` instead of `-fx-fill-text`

Comment: The example posted by betaman is a label css selector, -fx-text-fill should work for a label.  -fx-fill is for a Shape node - Text is a shape, but a Label is not.

Comment: @jewelsea "should work" yes, It might be a bug. But the spec. about CSS is from JavaFX 2.0, so things may have changed. That said, my answear is the workarround. (I edited my non-bug assumption)

Comment: The JavaFX css 2.1 specification is currently located at http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html (this is where I got my information from).

Comment: @jewelsea re-edited. Anyhow, the workarround just works fine.

Comment: @eversor  I tried your workaround and it does not work for me :(. I find no way to change the color of the label, either selected or unselected.

Comment: @jewelsea  what I've found is that it takes default values based on the -fx-base attributes (usually black or white depending on the intensity) and it is very hard or impossible to change those defaults using the stylesheet associated to the scene or to the object.

Comment: It does work when I assign the color directly using: button.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");   So I would say this is a bug in the way styleSheets are "hooked" to components.  It is much easier to use stylesheets than to assign values individually.  So This bug should be addressed if not already.

Comment: Moreover, there are things, like using _:hover_,  _:selected_,  _:focused_  states that cannot be specified in **setStyle**

Comment: betaman, bugs against the css component of the JavaFX platform can be logged at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com (Project Runtime | Component Control).  Include a short reproducible test case in the issue report and link to the issue from this StackOverflow question.